# Getting values of all id as type from an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object like

```
var myObj = [{ id: 'a', value: 1}, { id: 'b', value: 2 }, { id: 'c', value: 3}]
```

and I have a function to which I want to pass just possible value of ids

```
function abc(id: 'a' | 'b' | 'c') { /* */ }
```

I tried like this

```
var myObj = [{ id: 'a', value: 1}, { id: 'b', value: 2 }, { id: 'c', value: 3}]

type OJ = typeof myObj;
type id = keyof OJ[number]['id'];
```

but its showing id as
`type id = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | ... 30 more ... | "padEnd"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error will be fixed if you remove `keyof` from `type id = keyof OJ[number]['id'];`. This will make `id` match `string`. If you want more specific type, ie, you want `id` to be `"a" | "b" | "c"`, then you can give `as const` after the object.

```
function abc(id: 'a' | 'b' | 'c') { /* */ }

var myObj = [{ id: 'a', value: 1}, { id: 'b', value: 2 }, { id: 'c', value: 3}] as const

type OJ = typeof myObj;
type id = OJ[number]['id'];
//    ^?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwEYQBQwCYC5EDkyBiAPoaieQRAQJSIDeiA9AFSJsuIC+AUHwBuyAE6IAtgE8A8qgBWiALyIA2sxz4iBADSJhAGxABTfAEYeu9Xgo69yQycQAmXpcQbCtXQeP4AzDwAuigAzogQCCFQAlCSAA5GiNIAUkqIsQlwwBIy8gDcfBmJOGkpKmAg4qhGIoEqBDgEgQUs3IjtAHoA-EA)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `keyof` in your `type id`:

```
const myObj = [{ id: 'a', value: 1}, { id: 'b', value: 2 }, { id: 'c', value: 3}];

type OJ = typeof myObj;
type id = OJ[number]['id'];
```

With this approach, however, the type of `id` will be `string`, because TypeScript considers `myObj` to be open-ended and you could add additional elements to the `myObj` later on.

To prevent this, use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const myObj = [{ id: 'a', value: 1}, { id: 'b', value: 2 }, { id: 'c', value: 3}] as const;

type OJ = typeof myObj;
type id = OJ[number]['id'];
```